# Show login modal on unauthorized response angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I need to show a login modal every time the server returns a http unauthorized status (401), and in that case, stop the page loading... for example, I'm logged in but trying to access an protected resource that only admin users can do it.. so in that case I would like to show an modal with login and password to the user. It could be on navigating to a protected route or on delete event for example.

I tried to do it in an ApiInterceptor:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ApiInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    ...
  ) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    req = req.clone({ url: environment.baseUrl + req.url });

    if (this.authService.validToken) {
      req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.authService.validToken}`) });
    }

    if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
      req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
    }

    return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(resp => this.handleError(resp)));

  }

  private handleError(httpError: HttpErrorResponse) {
      if (httpError.status === this.UNAUTHORIZED) {
        // opening login modal here, but can't stop the request to prevent user to se unauthorized data, and after login, how can I redirect user to the same resource he tried to access?
      }
      return throwError(httpError);
  }

}
```

Need help here, if someone have an idea in how to do it will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your `ApiInterceptor` looks like it's for adding a bearer token to the request. I'd call this the `TokenInterceptor` or similar, and create a new one for handling unauthorised requests.

I'd create a new interceptor and call this `UnauthorisedRequestInterceptor`. Something similar to this:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UnauthorisedRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    intercept(
        req: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            map(event => {
                return event;
            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (error.status === 401) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
                }
                return throwError(error);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

This will intercept every http request, and if the returned status is 401, it will redirect you to your login page.

Then add this into your list of providers in `app.module.ts`:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: UnauthorisedRequestInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
```

As for redirecting users on access to a protected route, this should be done in your auth guard.

Comment: It is almost what I need, but instead of redirect to the login page, I wanna show the login modal, authenticate and then forward the request. Let me be clear, I am a user with no admin role, so if I try to delete an item for example that only admin could do it, I want to open a login modal, to the manager or anyone who has admin role type his user and password to authorize the action.

Comment: I see. What you need to do then is instead of navigating to the login page, display the login modal and return `empty()` from the `catchError`. When you display the modal, pass along the request to the modal, and resend that request, once the user has successfully logged in and you have stored their JWT token to use.

Comment: Exactly, I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

Every protected data that need roles or permissions should be on the server & have specific authorization to access it, if there is already protected data on your application you should consider moving it onto your server or add at least a guard.

If you want to redirect the user after a 401 you have to inject the Router service in your interceptor & use the `navigate` function (cf `this.router.navigate(['/myRoute']);` )